# Como clonar apenas um subdiretório do github

Tags: git, github

Supondo que tenha um diretório fictício no github:

*https://github.com/fulano/Diretorio*

E dentro de "Diretorio" tenha os subdiretórios:

*https://github.com/fulano/Diretorio/sub1*

*https://github.com/fulano/Diretorio/sub2*

É possível eu clonar somente o "sub1" sem ter que clonar todo o diretório "Diretorio"?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa postagem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951

Comment: Valeu  @FelipeJ.R.Vieira Era Justamente isso que eu estava procurando!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De maneira geral não rola, uma das características do Git é ser 8 ou 80. Tem como fazer certos isolamentos para trabalhar de forma granular, mas clonar é uma operação fundamental que não tem o que fazer, tem que baixa tudo mesmo. Git não é solução para todos os problemas, por isso até sugere-se algumas técnicas para evitar essas deficiências (plausíveis, diga-se de passagem).

Mas aparentemente isso mudou :) Ver o comentário postado pelo Felipe aí em cima. [No SO tem como fazer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/13738951#13738951), mas tem que mexer no original para poder fazer, ainda não é algo direto. Vou dar uma estudada para postar melhor aqui.

Comment: Fechou @Maniero, obrigado!!